# c++ operator* throws a "read access violation" error

Tags: c++, exception, struct

I'm trying to create a Vector3 struct but everytime I use the operator * it seems to throw an exception
"read access violation".
I'm relevantly new to c++ and have no idea what is causing this.
VS 2017, Debug, x86

Code

```
    float x, y, z;

    Vec3 operator+(Vec3 d) {
        return { x + d.x, y + d.y, z + d.z };
    }
    Vec3 operator-(Vec3 d) {
        return { x - d.x, y - d.y, z - d.z };
    }
    Vec3 operator*(float d) {
        return { x * d, y * d, z * d }; // throwing an exception
        /*
        Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
        this was 0x302C.*/
    }

    void Normalize() {
        while (y < -180) {
            y += 360;
        };
        while (y > 180) {
            y -= 360;
        };
        if (x > 89) {
            x = 89;
        };
        if (x < -89) {
            x = -89;
        };
    }
};
```

```
// example code
uintptr_t c= *(uintptr_t*)(ModuleHandle+ 0x2);
Vec3* b= (Vec3*)(c+ 0x1); 
Vec3 a= *b* 2;
```

Comment: What does `(Vec3*)(c+ 0x1); ` mean to you? It's very likely to be the source of your problems.

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `c`? Something we can compile and debug to help answer your question. Without a complete MCVE we are left guessing unless there is an obvious error.

Comment: Well what the heck is `c` now? Run this in your debugger and tell us what line this is happening on!!!

Comment: I suspect `c` is a `Vec3*`

Comment: @MooingDuck With `(Vec3*)` it could be just about anything. I imagine that if it's there, it was probably added to fix some sort of compiler error. To me, it seems more likely that it's anything *but* `Vec3*`. Hopefully we'll see.

Comment: Critical tip when learning C++: Don't use pointers, and don't use `new`. Once you get the hang of the language, you can start using pointers, but still never use `new`.

Comment: "_`uintptr_t c= *(uintptr_t*)(ModuleHandle+ 0x2); Vec3* b= (Vec3*)(c+ 0x1);`_" - but, why?!

Comment: It looks like you are using memory mapped register or device on an embedded system. All we can say is that how you are mapping is definitely wrong. That is what the error you are getting means. We don't know what your mapping it and there are countless reasons it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a star before `b`:

```
Vec3 a= *b* 2;
```

Edit in regards to edited question, the other line of code above it seems to be the issue now:

```
Vec3* b= (Vec3*)(c+ 0x1);
```

If `c` isn't an array of at least 2 properly initialized `Vec3` instances, dereferencing that is going to cause the access violation you're seeing.

And I mean literally of `Vec3*` or `Vec3[]` type, not a `char*` or something. Because you're adding 1 to it, the type of the array has to be of the type of an individual item so the CPU knows how much to move the pointer forward by.

Comment: Snap downvotes without comment have been a problem lately on SO. But the access violation does point to an abused pointer and `b` is `Vec3` -- so you are likely right.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The question got edited a bunch of times, sometimes with `b`, sometimes without `b` and even once where `b` was a pointer. It doesn't appear in the revisions because they were done in quick succession. Edit : It's back to being a pointer...

Comment: That is actually how it looks in my source code but just different val names and a different address

Comment: @Blindy The question was edited and invalidated this answer. You should probably delete it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux in the latest revision I see there's still the errant star, so as far as I'm concerned my answer is still correct.

Comment: Actually it's even worse now, why is it setting `Vec3* b= (Vec3*)(c+ 0x1);` ???

Comment: Removing the star in my source just causes it to error

Comment: If removing the star causes an error, and having the star causes a different error, it's likely that `c` is not a `Vec3*` and you're trying to cast it to a `Vec3*`.

Comment: @Blindy Yes, that's the new mystery. But now that `b` is a pointer the `*` before `b` in the initialization of `a` is no longer errant as it dereferences the pointer so you can use operators on the `Vec3`.

Comment: I would delete this answer and make a new one. You aren't limited to 1 answer per question. The original answer and following comments are not irrelevant. Better to start fresh. Edit : answer*

Comment: I now added what c is.